# Creating Store View generates an error... I'm having trouble understanding it

Tags: magento-1.7, store-view

I'm taking a look at a friend's Magento website - they want to run a multi-store setup which I have done before on my own website.

So anyway, I make the new Website, make the new Store, all good so far.
I try to make a new Store View and it gives me the "Error creating store view - An error occurred while saving. Please review the error log' message.

I've tried going through exception.log but I can't quite make out what is causing the issue...

I know that whatever it is, is staring me in the face, but I'm glancing right over it...

Can anyone shame me and point out where I'm going wrong?

Not sure if relevant but this particular Magento installation has an insane amount of extensions...

---

extract from  exception.log

---

```
2016-08-12T12:37:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Trace: #0 /home/idsuppli/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/idsuppli/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/idsuppli/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/idsuppli/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_st...', Array)
#4 /home/idsuppli/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_st...', Array)
#5 /home/idsuppli/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(265): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(ET_CurrencyManager_Model_Store), Array, 'code')
#8 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/community/MageParts/Base/Helper/Data.php(199): Mage_Core_Model_Store->load(Array)
#9 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/community/MageParts/Permissions/Helper/Data.php(927): MageParts_Base_Helper_Data->getStoreId()
#10 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/community/MageParts/Permissions/Helper/Data.php(990): MageParts_Permissions_Helper_Data->getConfigTableEntry('mageparts_permi...', 'model', 'core/store')
#11 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/community/MageParts/Permissions/Model/Observer/Global.php(52): MageParts_Permissions_Helper_Data->clearModelCache('core/store')
#12 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): MageParts_Permissions_Model_Observer_Global->refreshModelCache(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(MageParts_Permissions_Model_Observer_Global), 'refreshModelCac...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('model_save_afte...', Array)
#15 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(465): Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_afte...', Array)
#16 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#17 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/StoreController.php(221): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#18 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_System_StoreController->saveAction()
#19 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#20 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/idsuppli/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/idsuppli/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in this line:

```
/home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/community/MageParts/Base/Helper/Data.php(199): Mage_Core_Model_Store->load(Array)
```

The call to `->load()` should be passed in an integer but is instead being given an array.

Take a look at line# 199 in file `/home/idsuppli/public_html/app/code/community/MageParts/Base/Helper/Data.php`. You should be able to backtrack it from there.

The final error is an SQL error resulting from the model being passed an array.

In fact, if you want to see the query thats causing the problem, go to `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and set the following properties to true.

```
protected $_debug = false; //change to true
protected $_logAllQueries = false; //change to true
```

All queries that take place will be logged in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`. You can search for the offending query there as well and that should also provide you with some insight as to what's going on.

Comment: @RaymondMorgan, did my answer get you going in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Shawn, my profuse apologies for taking so long to get back to you. Something urgent came up and I was offline for a while --- anyway your answer was PERFECT! Found the offending code, as per your direction and she's running!

Comment: Awesome! I am glad I was able to help!

Btw, don't forget to turn off query logging bc it can slow down performance on a production environment.